# Objects generated with createGraphics() using p5.js are not being garbage-collected

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, p5.js

I'm working on a simple drawing sketch where I want to give the user the undo functionality. To do that, I decided to keep track of every stroke (draw a line, change colors, ...) the user makes within an object created with ***createGraphics()*** which, in turn, is managed in an array treated like a stack (LIFO). After some testing I noticed that the amount of memory used by the browser was never decreasing and read in the [p5.js repo](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/1785) that the issue has to be addressed by using ***remove()*** , which I did to no avail.

Since I couldn't find a lot of information about it, I assume that the ***remove()*** method works as it should and the problem is in my implementation. Here's a very down to the bone sketch that replicates the issue:

```
function setup(){
    c = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    mouseClicked = mo;
}

function mo(){
    let ppp = createGraphics(5000, 5000); // oversized to make the memory usage obvious
    ppp.background(color(random(255), random(255), random(255)));
    image(ppp, 0, 0);
    ppp.remove();
    ppp = null;
}
```

The previous snippet will use around 100MB of memory every click, but, interestingly enough, only start to do so after the third click.

How am I doing it wrong? How do I successfully delete an object created with ***createGraphics()*** and free the memory it uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue is in the p5 libraries, specifically in p5.Graphics.js. Luckily, the good [people](https://github.com/meiamsome) at github came through with a [solution](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/pull/2788). For now, it's possible to solve the problem by overriding the remove function with:

```
p5.Graphics.prototype.remove = function() {
    if (this.elt.parentNode) {
      this.elt.parentNode.removeChild(this.elt);
    }
    var idx = this._pInst._elements.indexOf(this);
    console.log(this._pInst);
    if (idx !== -1) {
      this._pInst._elements.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    for (var elt_ev in this._events) {
      this.elt.removeEventListener(elt_ev, this._events[elt_ev]);
    }
};
```